# OpenJDK9 Missing in Alpine Linux

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux

I've had a container that's successfully used the following command to install OpenJDK9 in Alpine Linux for months.

```
apk add --no-cache -X http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing openjdk9
```

However, suddenly the command is now outputting the following

```
apk add --no-cache -X http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing openjdk9
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  openjdk9 (missing):
    required by: world[openjdk9]
```

Has AlpineLinux removed the package? I see it in http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/s390x/ but not in x86_64. Any ideas?

Comment: Use either 8 or 11

Comment: 8 works. 11 has the same error.

Answer (score 3):

The `openjdk9` package has recently moved from the `edge/testing` repository to `edge/community` (by this [PR](https://github.com/alpinelinux/aports/pull/8412)):

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/openjdk9

Therefore, try adding `http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community` to your `/etc/apk/repositories`, update and retry.

Answer (score 2):

JDK 9 is not supported anymore (since March 2018) you should pick one of the supported versions:

- Java 8 (**LTS**)
- Java 11 (**LTS**)
- Java 12 (non LTS)
- *Java 13*

And maybe choose a Long Term Support so either 8 or 11.

It's for this reason that the [OpenJDK images](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk/) are not shipped with other version

Refs:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history
- https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/java-se-support-roadmap.html
- https://adoptopenjdk.net/support.html#roadmap

Comment: True, but not an answer to the question, regarding OpenJDK Alpine package availability.

Comment: @valiano You're right, my answer concerns more a probable root cause than the question itself. I wanted to go beyond and advise to think about updating. Your answer is the perfect complement :-).